# Adding HTML codes inside PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm trying to add a view button to my table but I'm getting a syntax error, unexpected href. Seems like I'm wrong with the formatting. Still trying to learn PHP but is it possible to add href to the table?

Here's my code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["temperature"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["phoneno"].'</td>
            <td> '<a href='read.php?id='. $row['id'] .'' title='View Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><i class='fa fa-eye' style='font-size:30px; color: black;''></i></a>';' </td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
echo $output;
```

And here's the image for the color coding that seems wrong.

[image: sublime]

Comment: It is because you're using single quotes to delimit your strings while using single quotes in the strings to denote values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you're using single quotes to delimit your strings while using single quotes in the strings to denote values.

This -

```
<td> '<a href='read.php?id='. $row['id'] .'' title='View Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><i class='fa fa-eye' style='font-size:30px; color: black;''></i></a>';' </td>
```

Should be this -

```
<td><a href="read.php?id='. $row['id'] .'" title="View Record" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-eye" style="font-size:30px; color: black;"></i></a></td>';
```

Comment: I was able to understand after reading this article **PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them** but the answer is a good guide that would help. Thanks so much for the help!!

Answer (score 3):

Just mismatched quotes.

There're many ways to mix PHP and HTML and you've chosen a hard syntax. Please compare with e.g.:

```
<?php foreach($foo as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $row["name"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["temperature"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $row["phoneno"] ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href='read.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>' title='View Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><i class='fa fa-eye' style='font-size:30px; color: black;'></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php }
```

BTW, your are injecting raw text into HTML, beware that it can break your markup any time.

Comment: I flip flop between the two myself. When I can, I use the above method, however if I have to put all the html into a variable for method return, I do the concat style in the OP (because I detest using ob_funcs to capture pieces). All good examples here.

Answer (score 2):

Your quotes are all over the place. You open a string variable with single quotes so every time you use single quotes unescaped in the string you just created will be interrupted.

It should be like this: `<a href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'" ... >`